# How to install multiple modules with composer at once?

Tags: 8, composer

Let's say we need to install these 2 modules :

```
composer require 'drupal/redirect:^1.4'
composer require 'drupal/pathauto:^1.4'
```

I couldn't find the correct syntax so I've tried this but it doesn't work :

```
composer require 'drupal/redirect:^1.4'; 'drupal/pathauto:^1.4'
composer require 'drupal/redirect:^1.4', 'drupal/pathauto:^1.4'
composer require 'drupal/redirect:^1.4'/'drupal/pathauto:^1.4'
```

Actually I install 1st module "redirect " and after installation is completed, I install the 2nd one "pathauto".

I would like to create a script that will install all the necessary modules I need.

Comment: This is more a composer based question rather than Drupal. But have you tried just a space between each item? That's the usual way in composer to list multiple packages

Comment: You're right, just a space is enough `composer require 'drupal/adminimal_theme:^1.5' 'drupal/adminimal_admin_toolbar:^1.9'`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can write the names of multiple packages separated by spaces. For example:

```
composer require drupal/adminimal_theme:^1.5 drupal/adminimal_admin_toolbar:^1.9
```